# Minimum number of simplices for a generator of $H_q(S^q)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Is there a chain representing a generator of $H_q(S^q)$ consisting of only one simplex?

Here $S^q$ denotes the q-dimensional sphere and the answer can be given either for simplicial or singular homology.

The question makes sense only for q > 0, since $H_0(S^0) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

I know already that a generator can always be represented by a chain consisting of two simplices, e.g., gluing two q-simplices $\Delta_1^q, \Delta_2^q$ along their boundary in such a way that their difference $\Delta_1^q - \Delta_2^q$ is a cycle. Then this cycle represents also a generator of  $H_q(S^q)$.

In the case q = 1, the answer is *yes*, since we can wrap the unit interval once around the circle such that the two endpoints of the interval are mapped to one point on the circle. So we get a cycle and one can also show that this cycle is homologous to $\Delta_1^1 - \Delta_2^1$, which is a generator of $H_1(S^1)$.

But what about the case q > 1?

Comment: As Martin points out below, this cannot be done in general in singular (simplicial) homology, but it can definitely be done using cellular homology. The sphere is a cell complex with a 0-cell and an n-cell, and the cellular homology chain complex has one generator for every cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that, for odd dimensional spheres, you might be able to proceed in the same way as you did for $\mathbb{S}^1$. Any $n$-simplex is homeomorphic to an $n$-cell (or $n$-ball), and gluing the boundary of an $n$-cell to a single point, you get the $n$-sphere. If $n$ is odd, the singular $n$-simplex $\varphi$ obtained this way is a cycle; we have 
$$ \partial \varphi = \sum_{i = 0}^{n} (-1)^{i} \partial_{i}\varphi, $$
and since $\partial_{0} \varphi = \partial_{1} \varphi = \ldots = \partial_{n} \varphi$, and the number of terms is even, we get $0$ (for $n$ even, we have $\partial \varphi = \partial_0 \varphi \neq 0$). I don't think it is going to be too difficult to show that this simplex is homologous to the generator $\Delta_1^n - \Delta_2^n$.

For the even case, you actually *need* two simplices; no singular $2k$-simplex $\psi$ for $k \geq 1$ can *ever* be a cycle, since $\partial \psi$ is an alternating sum of an odd number of *basis elements* in a free abelian group.